# jQuery Asual Address Plugin causing IE6 "nonsecure items" warning

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, ssl, internet-explorer-6

The title pretty much says it all.  If I include the [Asual Address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/)  for jQuery in my project IE6 warns the user about "both secure and nonsecure items".  I've stripped a page down to nothing but:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head runat="server">
        <title>Title</title>
   </head>
<body>
    <script src="js/jquery.1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/jquery.address-1.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Place that in a secure site and IE6 will throw the warning.  I've looked in the source for the common culprit that is an `iframe` with an `"about:blank"` `src` tag but didn't see anything that looked like a problem.

Any help is appreciated.

**Update**: I've tried Fiddler to determine where the nonsecure item is coming from.  The only three things listed are:

```
200   HTTPS   CONNECT         *websiteurl*:443
200   HTTPS   *websiteurl*    Default.aspx
200   HTTPS   *websiteurl*    /js/jquery.1.4.4.min.js
200   HTTPS   *websiteurl*    /js/jquery.address-1.3.min.js
```

The difference comes if I click "No" to loading the nonsecure items. I get

```
200   HTTPS   CONNECT         *websiteurl*:443
200   HTTPS   *websiteurl*    Default.aspx
200   HTTPS   *websiteurl*    /js/jquery.1.4.4.min.js
200   HTTPS   *websiteurl*    /js/jquery.address-1.3.min.js
400   HTTPS   *websiteurl*    pagerror.gif
```

I've researched the `pagerror.gif`, but It comes after I've told IE *not* to load the nonsecure items, so I'm not sure it's related to my issue.

Comment: oops sorry about my bogus (deleted) answer - I totally misunderstood that sentence about `<iframe>` tags :-)

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I finally found it.  Turns out, it was a problem with an iframe source.

For future readers: In the plugin, you'll need to give the iframe a src when it's created.  `javascript:false;` works nicely.  So, find the line that reads

```
 _frame = _d.createElement((frameset ? '' : 'i') + 'frame');
```

and change it to

```
_frame = _d.createElement((frameset ? '' : 'i') + 'frame');
_frame.src = 'javascript:false;';
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

1 - Download [Fiddler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/version.asp) or [HttpFox](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/HttpFox.shtml) (or any suitable web debugging proxy).

2 - Clear your browser cache.

3 - Using one of those programs, view everything fetched from your site. The culprit is the non-https requested resource.

Comment: Yeah, I should have said, I've tried that.  I'll update the question.